# Posting XML Data from a MVC application

Tags: xml, model-view-controller, httpwebrequest, service

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC Application that has to consume data from 3rd party Web services using XML Post.

I know I can work with a XSD generated class or a static XML template files to make web requests from the controller, but they both are CPU and I/O expensive and most importantly not easy to maintain solutions.

What would be the best way to implment this from maintainability and performance point of view?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way of doing this would be to create an XMLResult class which inherits from ActionResult. Just the way you can return plain text or Json or any others of the built-in results, you should be able to create an XMLResult as well.

EDIT: There you go:

- http://www.hackersbasement.com/csharp/post/2009/06/07/XmlResult-for-ASPNet-MVC.aspx
- http://kurtschindler.net/blog/post/Creating-an-ActionResult-that-returns-XML-with-ASPNET-MVC

EDIT 2: Ok if you're looking to manipulate XML in your controller, the most intuitive way (at least that's the way I see it) would be to use LINQ-to-XML. Here are some useful links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx
- http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/10/understanding-c-simple-linq-to.html
- http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/net30/article.php/c13715

I hope that was helpful. :)

Comment: XMLResults class would be perfect, but I need to access the XML data from the controller, not the view.

Comment: Ok I have just edited my answer and included some links that would allow you to manipulate XML in your controller.